NETWORK_NOT_PEERED trying to create an AlloyDB instance through gcloud CLI
I'm trying to create an AlloyDB instance using the gcloud CLI using these commands:
gcloud alloydb clusters create default \
  --region=$LOCATION \
  --password=postgres

gcloud alloydb instances create default \
  --cluster=default \
  --region=$LOCATION \
  --cpu-count=2 \
  --instance-type=PRIMARY

The first command succeeds, but the second fails with:
service networking config validation failed NETWORK_NOT_PEERED - no peering found on network, see https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/configure-connectivity for details

I believe I have to manually configure the peering network but I can't understand how? If I add the --enable-private-service-connect  flag the instance is successfully created but then I'm unable to reach it from my GKE cluster, and I see the AlloyDB cluster has an empty "Network" entry.

I managed to create the instance with these commands:
gcloud alloydb clusters create default \
  --region=$LOCATION \
  --password=postgres \
  --network=default

gcloud compute addresses create servicenetworking-googleapis-com \
    --global \
    --purpose=VPC_PEERING \
    --addresses=192.168.0.0 \
    --prefix-length=16 \
    --network=default

gcloud services vpc-peerings connect \
    --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com \
    --ranges=servicenetworking-googleapis-com \
    --network=default

gcloud alloydb instances create default \
  --cluster=default \
  --region=$LOCATION \
  --cpu-count=2 \
  --instance-type=PRIMARY


You can use commands provided in AlloyDB codelabs. Here is a couple of examples:

one - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/alloydb-ai-embedding#create-private-ip-range
two - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/genai-db-retrieval-app#create-private-ip-range

And don't forget to enable the APIs like servicenetworking.googleapis.com
